# Errored - execute npm command "run build-prod" on Azure Web Service

Tags: angular, azure, npm

I am publishing a demo angular 4/webapi web app on Azure cloud via VSTS CI/CD platform. I have been facing an issue with build configuration, specific to npm install and build commands.

npm install runs successfully, i can see the console window. However, the build queue is getting broken as soon as run build-prod is fired.

I confirm the package.json file is present in the root folder.

More console errors below:-
[image]

Comment: What Service in Azure are you trying to use?  The Azure Apps Service, The Azure Functions Service, The Azure Virtual Machine Service?

Comment: Sir, it's Azure App Service. I feel it should not differ on the basis of different services though.